# Rows getting deleted when i update the timestamp?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I thought this was fairly simple. I need to update four rows with a certain user_id parameter(say 'XYZ' such that the time values in the timestamps are reset to 12 am.

I have 4 rows with this user_id in that table.

I run the following query:

```
update table_to_be_updated
set table_timestamp = to_timestamp(to_date(table_timestamp , 'yyyy/mm/dd'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
    where user_id = 'XYZ';
```

The query runs fine. Next, I try selecting all rows that have `user_id = 'XYZ'`, and the rows are gone! Can someone help with that is going wrong? I cannot see the rows in the select unless i rollback.

Comment: An `update` won't delete rows unless you have some other code that you haven't mentioned here.  If the table is actually a view with an instead of trigger or if there is a statement level trigger on the table that deletes rows incorrectly, that might explain what you're seeing.  I'd be pretty wary about your `UPDATE` statement since it will error out if your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` or `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` isn't what you're implicitly expecting.  But that won't cause rows to be deleted.

Comment: Maybe your table has a index for uniqueness

Comment: There are no other queries on there. Once the update executes, it tells me 4 rows were updated. Is there a better way for me to make this update? Idea is, if the timestamp is 2/21/2015 05:03:55, it should become 2/21/2015 00:00:00

Comment: As an aside, you know you could just `trunc()` the values to reset the time portion to midnight, right? That returns a date, but it would be cast back to a timestamp automatically. When you query after the update are you only filtering on the user ID, or also on the date you think it's now suppoed to have?

Comment: so, I finally got what was wrong (sorry couldn't update earlier).

Comment: i was running the query:
update table_to_be_updated set table_timestamp = to_timestamp(to_date(table_timestamp , 'yyyy/mm/dd'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), user_id = 'ABC'
    where user_id = 'XYZ'; Looks like the new user id wasn't getting recorded. It was getting overwritten by the system's id. when i was querying after the update, i was looking for ABC and i could find no rows.